# How to cast all columns of Spark dataset to string using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with so many columns and I want to cast all columns to the string using Java.

I tried below steps, I want to know if there is any better way to achieve this?

```
Dataset<Row> ds = ...;
JavaRDD<String[]> stringArrRDD = ds.javaRDD().map(row->{
          int length = row.length();
          String[] columns = new String[length];
          for(int i=0; i<length;i++){
              columns[i] = row.get(i) !=null? row.get(i).toString():"";
          }
       return  columns;});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate over `columns`:

```
for (String c: ds.columns()) {
    ds = ds.withColumn(c, ds.col(c).cast("string"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use objects only:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
...
for (String c: ds.columns()) {
    ds = ds.withColumn(c, ds.col(c).cast(DataTypes.StringType));
}
```