# How to cast all columns of Spark Dataset to String in Java without withColumn?

Tags: java, apache-spark, casting

I've tried the solution using withColumn specified here:

[How to cast all columns of Spark dataset to string using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826020/how-to-cast-all-columns-of-spark-dataset-to-string-using-java)

But, the solution is taking a hit on performance for huge number of columns (1k-6k). It takes more than 6 hours and then gets aborted.

Alternatively, I'm trying to use map to cast like below, but I get error here:

```
MapFunction<Column, Column> mapFunction = (c) -> {
    return c.cast("string");
};      

dataset = dataset.map(mapFunction, Encoders.bean(Column.class));
```

Error with above snippet:

```
The method map(Function1<Row,U>, Encoder<U>) in the type Dataset<Row> is not applicable for the arguments (MapFunction<Column,Column>, Encoder<Column>)
```

Import used:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the below solution for anyone looking for this:

```
String[] strColNameArray = dataset.columns();
List<Column> colNames = new ArrayList<>();
for(String strColName : strColNameArray){
    colNames.add(new Column(strColName).cast("string"));
}
dataset = dataset.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(colNames));`
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean 1k-6k columns or do you mean rows?

But in any case I cast columns genericly like this:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)).toDF("a", "b")

val cols = for {
  a <- df.columns
} yield col(a).cast(StringType)

df.select(cols : _*)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. But this is in Scala. I needed the code snippet for Java.
But I figured it out later. I used :

  `String[] strColNameArray = dataset.columns();`
  `List<Column> colNames = new ArrayList<>();`
  `for(String strColName : strColNameArray){`
  `colNames.add(new Column(strColName).cast("string"));`
  `}`
  `dataset = dataset.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(colNames));`

Comment: sry about that it looks like I didnt fully read your question

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your help!